How can I interpret the accuracy of a Newton solver with a given tolerance?
A piece of software I've inherited seems to implement the k-variable, k-function variation of a Newton solver to solve a system of equations. I'm relatively new to this area, so apologize if I'm getting some terminology wrong, but this is my understanding of what's going on:

The code stores the variables in a vector $v$ and evaluates the equations with the current values of the variables and stores that in a "residuals" vector, $b$.

It evaluates partial derivatives of the equations in a matrix $A$.

It uses Gauss elimination to solve for $x$ in $A \cdot x = b$.

It then uses the $x$ vector to calculate adjustments for the next values of the variables ($v' = v - x$).

Repeat until the maximum value $\Delta_{max}$ in the this vector is below some $\epsilon$
$$\Delta_{max} = max(\frac{|x_i|}{|v_i|+|x_i|})$$
$$\Delta_{max} < \epsilon$$


What I'm trying to understand is how do I interpret $\epsilon$? What "units" would it have? I understand vaguely that a bigger $\epsilon$ lets the algorithm say "good enough" sooner and would be less accurate, but how could I communicate to someone else how accurate the algorithm "guarantees" the variables to be for a given $\epsilon$ if the algorithm converges.
To motivate why I'm asking, we have two implementations of this algorithm in different languages. We've found that at iteration $n$, for one environment $\Delta_{max} < \epsilon$, but for the other, $\Delta_{max} > \epsilon$, so the first exits, but the second takes another iteration. But at iteration $n + 1$, $\Delta_{max} \ll \epsilon$. What I'd like to know is what's the maximum theoretical difference between two solutions such that in the first $\Delta_{max} \approx \epsilon$ but in the second $\Delta_{max} \approx 0$.
For now I'm not interested in "real world" factors like floating point error, just what a strict interpretation of that value means.

@uhoh I thought this site might be more appropriate because I'm asking about what a value means in terms of matrices, specifically ignoring the computational accuracy. I'll post there too if I don't get responses here.

OK, but avoid cross-posting (same question simultaneously in multiple sites). It's discouraged because of answer-fragmentation. You can flag for moderator assistance to have the question migrated to SciComp SE if you don't have luck here.

This error tolerance is very nonstandard. One can see that $\Delta=0$ iff $x=0$ and $v\neq 0$, which implies convergence. As for how to interpret this, one can view this as a ratio of how large the step is for each variable to how large each variable actually is. To account for the case when $v_i=0$, we add $|x_i|$ in the denominator as well. This seems like it would have the effect of terminating the iteration only when the steps being taken are much smaller than the magnitudes of the variables.
For example, if we consider one dimension and take a step of $x=1$, then $\Delta$ gets changes depending on where we take that step from. If $v=1000$, we have $\Delta = \frac{1}{1001}$, but if $v=0$, we have $\Delta = 1$. One may terminate and the other will not. This seems to be a form of central bias, as the iteration will continue for longer when $v$ is small and hence solutions far from the origin may be resolved with less accuracy. In fact, it looks like the iteration may not converge at all if the solution is $v=0$, since $\Delta$ is always equal to $1$ in this case. This is bizarre.
A more common convergence criteria for Newton's method is
$$
\|F(v)\| < \tau_r \|F(v_0)\| + \tau_a,
$$
where $v_0$ is the initial guess and $\tau_r$ and $\tau_a$ are relative and absolute tolerances, respectively. This has the effect of ensuring that $F(v)$ gets closer to $0$ regardless of the relative sizes of the entries of $v$.

Thanks for the answer - upon a second review of the code I found that when calculating $\Delta_{max}$, it ignores values of $v < 0.1$. This logic of terminating when the steps taken are small seems to loosely match the Python code on the Wikipedia page which terminates when $x_0 - x_1 < tol$ - is it different?

It is more common to see $|x_n|\leq tol$, but that is basically equivalent. It becomes less reliable for more exotic variants of Newton's method. For Newton, $|x_n| = |v_n-v^| + \mathcal{O}(|v_n-v^|^2)$  so the two criteria are roughly equivalent
